# Irritation with poor questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

[If I watch television on Friday night, will I go to hell?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18384/if-i-watch-television-on-friday-night-will-i-go-to-hell)

I am mildy surprised at the quick rejection (in the social sense) of this question. The comments convey exasperation and irritation with the poor quality of the question and then simply leave it at that. Aside from @IsaacMoses who (as always) is welcoming as well as critical, no one seems to be taking the questioner into account along with his question.

To me there is an clear emotional component of the question which shouts louder than a straightforward search for answers. Yes, this is not a baal-teshuvah support group or kiruv organisation, but even halacha takes into account a person's emotional state and so should we.

Obviously, the question is short on detail and needs elaboration, but it is not invalid. Instead of criticising its shortcomings simply address them in the answer, by pointing out implicit assumptions and supplying answers for both possibilities of circumstances where the questioner did not elaborate.

Comment: I read the comments as seeking clarification, not dismissive.  But you are right to raise this; I think there is a style of asking questions (like those in the comments) that comes naturally to our community that can be off-putting to outsiders.  Thank you for raising this.

Comment: I disagree with your evaluation of the comments. But it was thoroughly downvoted (not by me) and perhaps that is where you are getting your impressions from.

Comment: related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59369/166155 and whole host of other discussions over there.